# How to use angular slider?

Tags: angular

When I tried to include the angular material slider in my form no errors show up but the slider is not visible, even though I imported all necessary modules in app.module.ts.

What is my mistake? I hope someone can help me with this.

> Components HTML:

```
<html>
    <div class="addtask">
        <form>
           Task: <input type="text" ><br/>
           Parent Task: <input type="text"><br/>
           Priority :<mat-slider></mat-slider>
           Start Date: <input type="date time"><br/>
           End Date: <input type="date time"><br/>
        </form>
    </div>
</html>
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AddtaskComponent } from './addtask/addtask.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AddtaskComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatSliderModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Did you check for any errors?

Comment: Try to init it like min and max `<mat-slider
  tickInterval="1000"
  min="1"
  max="100000"></mat-slider>`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read the slider documentation:
https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview

and follow the example in the stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/ayvjmxgegkr?file=app%2Fslider-overview-example.ts

I know its not a clear answer, but the full configuration and example are already available there, so I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you actually need to install `angular material`.

- For npm it is: `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations`
- And for yarn it should be: `yarn add @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations`.

[Here](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) is a link to that reference.

If you have all of that (and the include in `app.module.ts` but I did see that you have that) You are probably missing the styling. Angular material components require a styling theme which you can read about [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming). If you just want to get started quickly (**please do read that link**) just copy this line: `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` into your `style.css` or (if your using scss) into your `style.scss`.

Hope I could help and welcome to StackOverflow :)